# microsoft visual studio code is not working

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

im trying to create an project in vs code using jupyter notebook having 101767 data but when im droping the nan values using df.dropna(), the whole window totally stucks and says:- windows not working.

i restart it but still no use

Comment: What happens outside of VS Code?

Comment: everything works fine

Comment: Can you show the code that you ran that caused this in your question?

Comment: df.dropna(), after executing this code its getting stucked and then im unable to perform any other operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my question, i dont know the reason of this issue, but my guess is its due to the current update of vs code version 1.77. when i tried df.dropna() it does not worked before but after trying df = df.dropna() it worked.

Comment: Thankyou for the reminder Deutrys.